# "find all references" does not work unless dependent files are open

Tags: typescript

i am working with vs 2012 / typescript 0.9. whenever i try to use the "find all references" function from within a typescript file, no references are found unless the dependent files are open. for example, take the following scenario:

1) in file1.ts i have a class called class1 
2) in file2.ts i have a class called class2 which makes use of class1

if in file1.ts i right click on class1 and choose "find all references", no references are found in file2.ts, UNLESS file2.ts is open.

i was wondering if this is a bug or something on my end that be causing the issue.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is **currently** by design.  In most projects you'll usually have a "core" type file which references directly or indirectly the other TypeScript files in the project.  I usually keep my "core" file open so that all the find all references and all other tooling pieces work.

So one thing to note (hinted this above) is that you just need to have a file open that indirectly references the files you're looking to have "checked".

Aka if you have:

**A.ts**

```
// Stuff
```

**B.ts**

```
/// <reference path="A.ts" />
```

**C.ts**

```
/// <reference path="B.ts" />
```

In **C.ts** you will be able to find definitions in **A.ts** because **B.ts** references **A.ts**.

Comment: thank you for your response... i can't say i like the "current" design but i get it... i wish things would just work as they do in C#... thank you

Answer (score 0):

Additional information to N. Taylor Mullen answer (since I can't comment yet):

The "find all references" dows not need any other file to be open besides the current file if the current file contains a direct or indirect reference to all other files. My file structure looks like this:

**A.ts**

```
/// <reference path="References.ts" />
```

**B.ts**

```
/// <reference path="References.ts" />
```

**C.ts**

```
/// <reference path="References.ts" />
```

**References.ts**

```
/// <reference path="jquery.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="A.ts" />
/// <reference path="B.ts" />
/// <reference path="C.ts" />
```

I added the jquery.d.ts in this example  to show that really all needed modules or their definiton-files are referenced in the **References.ts**.
My Referenes.ts contains about 25 references, but each other file has only one reference to the reference.ts file.