# typescript find all references is working now

Tags: typescript

a while back ago i posted an issue i was experiencing with using "find all references" in typescript... the original post is here: ["find all references" does not work unless dependent files are open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17280730/find-all-references-does-not-work-unless-dependent-files-are-open)

since then a coworker informed me that he was not experiencing this issue... i conducted a test and indeed it appears the issue i reported previously is no longer an issue... does anyone know whether or not this was fixed recently??? i did not see any mention of this in recent release notes... so now i am wondering whether this was ever even an issue...

thank you

Comment: This really doesn't feel on-topic or very useful on StackOverflow (it's a very small time period where this might be of use)? Why not look at Web Essentials or whatever tool you're using to enable TypeScript support in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened with 0.9.1-1

The latest version of typescript plugin automatically puts "all" your typescript files in scope. But even before this version I've been using grunt-ts to do a reference file generation : https://github.com/basarat/grunt-ts#reference-file-generation